# How to import subpackage Python 3.4

Tags: python, module, package

I am working in ProjectEuler problems. Lots of the problem share common algorithms such as prime factorization, thus it makes sense to build library scripts that store these algorithms.

As of now I have something like the following structure

```
ProjectEuler/
    001/
        euler001.py
    002/
        euler002.py
        supporting.txt
    utils/
        primes.py
        combinatorics.py
```

I want to be able from any problem file (e.g. `euler002.py` import functions from files in utils (e.g `primes.py`).

How should I go about this?

Comment: Here is about relative import: [How to do relative imports in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)

Comment: Woah, the duplicate post solutions look quite confusing. I would like something related to package structure, like an import, modifying my sys.path or PYTHONPATH seems like overkill. Is this some kind of antipattern?